# Copy large files (120MB) from one drive to Azure blob - Power automate

Tags: azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I am using the standard Power automate template to copy the files from one drive to Azure blob storage container.

Is there a limit on the maximum size of the file that you transfer?

I have to copy file of 120MB from onedrive to Azure blob and the flow is not getting triggered as it's not recognising the huge file.

If the size of the file is less than 50MB flow, it's triggering.

How do I copy large files through Power automate?

Comment: Maybe look at using an Azure function.  Large files aren't friendly to the LogicApps/PowerAutomate engine.

Comment: Hi @Skin, how to use Azure function?

Comment: If you're not a developer (i.e. you're not skilled in coding) then you're going to struggle.  Read up on the doco ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering using OneDrive connector is not possible through Power automate since this is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedrive/#known-issues-and-limitations) for this connector. The trigger starts to skip if the file is bigger than 50 MB.

> The When a file is created or when a file is modified triggers will skip every file bigger than 50 MB.

However, you can copy files by having a different trigger and copy files to Azure blob storage by having required condition. In my case I'm checking if the file is already present in the blob. If yes, it skips. If not, It creates the file in Blob Storage. Below is the flow.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***In my Storage account***

[image]

Comment: It might be a case where the file is already present. Also Can you please add what you have tried.

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda, thanks for this. It works when there is atleast one file in the blob storage container. It doesn't work if the container is completely empty. How to trigger the flow when a new file is created in one drive but still copy large files?

Comment: How do you want to handle it? Like the flow skips the condition part if there are no files inside onedrive

Comment: Files are there in onedrive but no files in blob storage and is empty. That's when it is not working. How to trigger the flow when a new file is created in one drive but still copy large files?

Comment: Triggering Large files more than 50MB in onedrive doesn't work since there is a limitation for it. This works with normal HTTP or Recurrence  triggers

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda, thanks. How to trigger this with normal HTTP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248445/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-and-sparc).